# How to place contact information in the right side of the header in Moderncv?

Tags: moderncv

I want to put my contact information and maybe also my photo to the right side of header. Would someone kindly tell me how i can do that? Bellow is the tex code of my document.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage{moderncvstyleclassic}
\moderncvcolor{red}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[scale=1, left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{pifont}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\LARGE\mdseries\upshape}


\firstname{Aa} 
\familyname{Bb} 
\title{Curriculum Vitae} 
\address{<JJJJ>}{<Addres Place>}    % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\mobile{<25454>}                    % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\phone{<456565>}                      % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\fax{<676767>}                          % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\email{<E-mail>}   



\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % ensure footer with personal information
  \makecvfooter%
  % optional picture
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
      {}%
      {%
       \setlength\fboxrule{\@photoframewidth}%
       \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
         \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
       {\color{color1}\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}}%
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  % name
  \@initializelength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}%
  \settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \parbox[b]{\textwidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{%
    \raggedright\namefont{\@firstname} {\@familyname}}\\[-.35em]% 
  {\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}}%
  % optional title
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\null\titlestyle{\@title}}\\[2.5em]  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\null\hfill\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\hfill\null\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}%
\makeatother
```

Comment: It would be super if you could complete your code snippet into a complete, compilable document.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as  you can see in the picture below, the personal information (address, email, contact, etc.) and the photo is by-default on the right side of the top header.

[image]

All you need to do, is to use the classic style of the moderncv template.

Comment: You'r right! In classic package it is like that. But I meant in casual package. And with classic package, could you please let me know how to make email address appear not in italic form? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to make any changes to the default settings, you'd better edit the style and class files of this template.